# Ipfix in openvSwitch

Tags: packet-analysis, ipfix, ovs

The *sampling* parameter in openvswitch to enable IPFIX what it refers to? For example, a value of 1 means what? Furthermore, as the difference there is *per-bridge sampling* and *per-flow sampling*?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly 1 out of *x* packets.  This is a common technique to reduce overhead for flow processing.  A value of 1 means no sampling.  If you use a higher value you need to make sure your collection / analysis tools are similarly configured to allow for proper interpolation.